# How to move wireless connection to other network namespace?

Tags: linux, wireless-networking

```
# ip link set  wlan0 netns 1
RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument
```

It works for usual ethernet. It also works for proprietary broadcom "wl" driver.

How to do it for usual mac80211-based driver?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to move the PHY:

```
iw phy phy0 set netns 666
```

Where 666 is the pid of some process running in that network namespace; for netspaces created by `iproute2` tools (with `ip netns`), you can create a short-lived process in there and get its pid:

```
iw phy phy0 set netns "$(ip netns exec mynetns sh -c '
  sleep 1 >&- & echo "$!"')"
```

To move it back to the root namespace:

```
ip netns exec mynetns iw phy phy0 set netns 1
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.

Comment: Crashed the kernel playing with `iw ... setns`...

Comment: What is the 666? Man says it is a pid, but a pid of which process should I provide here?

Comment: `666` is a PID of a process already in the network namespace you want to use. You can replace `666` by `name XXX` where `XXX` is the namespace's name.

Comment: `$ sudo iw phy phy0 set netns 19470`
`command failed: Operation not supported (-95)`

(FFS, I've edited this comment so many times but nothing is working; how do I do this on multiple lines?)

Comment: @flarn2006 the driver has to support it. A specific property must exist: `iw phy phy0 info | grep set_wiphy_netns`

Answer (score 1):

For wifi get the physical address of your interface first (in case your have more than 1 wireless card):

```
iw dev
```

The result will be somehting like this:

```
phy#0
        Interface wlp58s0
                ifindex 3
                wdev 0x1
                ...
```

So the name is `phy0`

now use that to assign your wifi to the namespace:

```
# iw phy phy0 set netns name <MyNamespace>
```

From the help of `iw`:

```
    phy <phyname> set netns { <pid> | name <nsname> }
            Put this wireless device into a different network namespace:
                <pid>    - change network namespace by process id
                <nsname> - change network namespace by name from /var/run/netns
                           or by absolute path (man ip-netns)
```

Comment: This answer repeats the accepted answer for the most part.
You may want to edit the accepted include information about how to find `phy` instead of posting a semi-redundant new answer.

Comment: His answer uses process ID, while there is an easier way to just use the name of the namespace. So his answer is still correct but I wanted to show the other possible way.

Answer (score 0):

Implemented my own workaround: [vethify](https://gist.github.com/vi/7057783)

1. Create a pair of virtual interfaces, move one of them (for example, veth1) into other namespace: `ip link add type veth`; `ip link set veth1 netns <some_pid>`;
2. Bring wlan0 interface and veth0 up, but don't add any addresses to it;
3. Start `vethify wlan0 veth0` on host network namespace. It will copy all captured on wlan0 to veth0 and back;
4. Configure IP address and routing in the other namespace on veth1;
5. Disable checksum offloading for veth1: `ethtool --offload veth1 rx off tx off && ethtool -K veth1 gso off`.

Note: vethify sees all packets in the network namespace, not only wlan0's and veth0's. It will add latency and cause additional overhead.