# Ping one interface from the other, same host

Tags: linux, networking, ping

I have a computer (running Linux) with two ethernet interfaces. I want to test them without involving another PC.

The setup:

```
  (192.168.1.5) eth1-------.
Linux PC/device            | loopback cable
  (192.168.1.6) eth2-------'
```

I run

```
ping -I eth1 192.168.1.6
```

but no reply comes.

I don't understand what the problem is. Why does Linux prevent this action? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Yes. I need to solve this problem. I want to test two ethernet interfaces without another PC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Why?

I cannot fully explain.

---

#### How can I solve this problem?

Usually [Linux reaches locally assigned IP addresses internally](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/408332/108618) and it just works. It seems the problem appears when one really needs packets to travel to the outside (e.g. via a cable) and back – like in your case.

You can make it work by using network namespaces. I adjusted [this other answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1516108/432690) to your needs.

Notes:

- I tested on Debian 10.
- Where the command is `ip …` you will probably need `sudo ip …`. For readability I omit `sudo`. Work in an elevated shell or (temporarily) define `alias ip='sudo ip'` to be able to copy-paste conveniently.
- I assume no automation interferes, i.e. there is no daemon that would try to configure the relevant interfaces in its own way.
- To run a command in a non-default network namespace I use `ip netns exec …`. It's possible to run a shell this way; then everything you run from the shell will use the network namespace. This answer uses `ip netns exec …` every time we need to run something in a non-default network namespace.

Proceed like this:

1. Define useful variables. Here `ns1` is an arbitrary name for a namespace; `eth1` and `eth2` are the devices you want to use.

   ```
   netns=ns1
   dev1=eth1
   dev2=eth2
   ```
2. Create a new network namespace.

   ```
   ip netns add "$netns"
   ```
3. Bring the devices down in the default namespace.

   ```
   ip link set dev "$dev1" down
   ip link set dev "$dev2" down
   ```
4. Add one of the devices to the new namespace (it will disappear from the default namespace). Here I choose to move `$dev2` to the new namespace.

   ```
   ip link set dev "$dev2" netns "$netns"
   ```
5. Assign IP addresses.

   ```
                          ip address add 192.168.1.5/24 dev "$dev1"
   ip netns exec "$netns" ip address add 192.168.1.6/24 dev "$dev2"
   ```
6. Confirm the two devices are where they should be, with the right IP addresses.

   ```
                          ip address show
   ip netns exec "$netns" ip address show
   # examine output
   ```
7. Physically connect the two interfaces with a cable, if not yet done.
8. Bring the interfaces up. The namespace contains its own loopback device `lo`. I bring it up just in case, because in general programs may want to rely on it.

   ```
                          ip link set dev "$dev1" up
   ip netns exec "$netns" ip link set dev "$dev2" up
   ip netns exec "$netns" ip link set dev      lo up
   ```
9. Check routes. In my Debian 10 sane routes appear automatically. This command

   ```
   ip route show
   ```

   prints (among other lines)

   ```
   192.168.1.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.5
   ```

   and this command

   ```
   ip netns exec "$netns" ip route show
   ```

   prints

   ```
   192.168.1.0/24 dev eth2 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.6
   ```
10. Ping one way or the other.

    ```
                           ping 192.168.1.6
    ip netns exec "$netns" ping 192.168.1.5
    ```

    You can use `-I` but it's not necessary. The address `192.168.1.6` is not assigned to any interface in the default network namespace; and `192.168.1.5` is not assigned in the non-default namespace.

And this is it. It should work. My tests indicate these `ping`s really use the cable. I can tell because:

- disconnecting the cable makes them stop flowing; for comparison: "internal" pings (from a wired interface to its own IP address) flow even without a cable;
- `iptraf-ng` monitoring the pinged interface shows ICMP echo requests and ICMP echo replies; for comparison: the tool doesn't show "internal" pings for a wired interface.

Basic cleanup: delete the network namespace.

```
ip netns del "$netns"
```

This will move the second device back to the default network namespace.

None of the commands we used implements a permanent change, so in case of any trouble just reboot.