# What does ping -n do differently?

Tags: linux, networking, dns, ping

While troubleshooting an occasional network "stall" on my home internet, I came across this [technical tip from Dell](https://www.dell.com/support/article/en-us/sln49664/when-executed-within-red-hat-linux-the-ping-command-may-hang-for-a-few-seconds-before-responding-technical-tip-162287?lang=en).  They suggest using `ping -n` to avoid a stall caused by DNS resolution.  This got me thinking, what does the `-n` switch actually do?  It seems to me that DNS resolution is required if you ping a DNS name, but not required if you ping an IP.

From the man page:
**-n**  *Numeric output only. No attempt will be made to lookup symbolic names for host addresses.*

If I ping an IP address like `ping 8.8.8.8` how is there any DNS lookup here?  Does `ping -n 8.8.8.8` do something different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I ping an IP address like `ping 8.8.8.8` how is there any DNS lookup here? Does `ping -n 8.8.8.8` do something different?

It may depend on the implementation. If `ping` without `-n` includes `dns.google` in its output, `ping -n` probably doesn't, this is the difference. But it's possible that neither output includes the string.

---

In my Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS `man 8 ping` reads:

> `ping` is part of `iputils` package and the latest versions are  available in source form at `http://www.skbuff.net/iputils/iputils-current.tar.bz2`.

This exact address seems not to work, still http://www.skbuff.net/iputils provides other links, including [the one to SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/p/iputils/code/ci/HEAD/tree/). I have downloaded [iputils-s20151218](http://www.skbuff.net/iputils/iputils-s20151218.tar.bz2) and read the code.

`-n` is handled in `ping_common.c`:

```
case 'n':
        options |= F_NUMERIC;
        break;
```

Then the option (`options & F_NUMERIC`) is important in `ping.c`:

```
pr_addr(__u32 addr)
{
        …

        if (exiting || (options & F_NUMERIC) ||
            !(hp = gethostbyaddr((char *)&addr, 4, AF_INET)))
                sprintf(buf, "%s", inet_ntoa(*(struct in_addr *)&addr));
        else {
                …
```

To get to `gethostbyaddr`, both `exiting` and `options & F_NUMERIC` must be false (because `a || b` does will not evaluate `b` if `a` is true). The latter depends on whether `-n` was or wasn't used.

`gethostbyaddr` is the "attempt to lookup symbolic names for host addresses". See `man 3 gethostbyaddr`. This is the same library call `getent hosts` uses when you provide an IP address (see `man 1 getent`).

See the difference:

```
$ getent hosts 8.8.8.8
8.8.8.8         dns.google
$ ping -c 1 dns.google
…
64 bytes from dns.google (8.8.8.8): icmp_seq=1 ttl=120 time=10.6 ms
…
$ ping -n -c 1 dns.google
…
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=120 time=11.3 ms
…
$
```

It may seem `ping` without `-n` just uses the string the user provided; but no:

```
$ getent hosts poczta.wp.pl
193.17.41.99    poczta.wp.pl
$ getent hosts 193.17.41.99
193.17.41.99    poczta.o2.pl
$ ping -c 1 poczta.wp.pl
…
64 bytes from poczta.o2.pl (193.17.41.99): icmp_seq=1 ttl=60 time=9.71 ms
…
$
```

Here `poczta.wp.pl` was resolved to `193.17.41.99` and then `193.17.41.99` was resolved to `poczta.o2.pl` (note `o2` instead of `wp`). Usage of `-n` would suppress the latter step.

For some addresses this happens:

```
$ getent hosts superuser.com
151.101.1.69    superuser.com
151.101.193.69  superuser.com
151.101.65.69   superuser.com
151.101.129.69  superuser.com
$ getent hosts 151.101.1.69 151.101.193.69 151.101.65.69 151.101.129.69        
$        # the output was empty
$ ping -c 1 superuser.com
…
64 bytes from 151.101.1.69 (151.101.1.69): icmp_seq=1 ttl=58 time=37.1 ms
…
$ ping -n -c 1 superuser.com
…
64 bytes from 151.101.1.69: icmp_seq=1 ttl=58 time=36.8 ms
…
$
```

**But** if I provide a numeric address then there will be no difference:

```
$ getent hosts 8.8.8.8
8.8.8.8         dns.google
$ ping -c 1 8.8.8.8
…
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=120 time=10.8 ms
…
$ ping -n -c 1 8.8.8.8
…
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=120 time=8.91 ms
…
$
```

It's because of this fragment from `ping.c`:

```
if (inet_aton(target, &whereto.sin_addr) == 1) {
        hostname = target;
         if (argc == 1)
                 options |= F_NUMERIC;
} else
```

`inet_aton` converts from the IPv4 numbers-and-dots notation into binary form. It returns `1` on success. If the last argument given to `ping` can be converted, the fragment evaluates `options |= F_NUMERIC` *as if `-n` was used*.

I actually compiled `ping` from the source in two versions: the original and with `if … options |= F_NUMERIC;` commented out. The modified version behaves like this:

```
$ ./ping -c 1 8.8.8.8
…
64 bytes from dns.google (8.8.8.8): icmp_seq=1 ttl=120 time=9.67 ms
…
$ ./ping -n -c 1 8.8.8.8
…
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=120 time=8.69 ms
…
$
```

Now I can explicitly answer the question:

> Does `ping -n 8.8.8.8` do something different [than `ping 8.8.8.8`]?

**No. The address in the IPv4 numbers-and-dots notation makes `ping` (from `iputils` on Linux) work as if `-n` was used.**

---

> If I ping an IP address like `ping 8.8.8.8` how is there any DNS lookup here?

I created a separate network namespace (to make sure as little traffic as possible interferes) with a veth pair, then used `wireshark` there. (If you want to replicate my results and need help with the procedure, see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1516108/432690), example 2).

With the original `ping`:

- `ping -n -c 1 8.8.8.8` generates `ICMP echo request` and receives `ICMP echo reply`. No DNS involved.
- `ping -c 1 8.8.8.8` does the same (no surprise here, explained above).

This means **there is no DNS lookup**. Below are some tests for comparison.

With my modified `ping`:

- `ping -n -c 1 8.8.8.8` behaves like the original.
- `ping -c 1 8.8.8.8` queries the DNS server after ICMP and receives a response. This is to get `dns.google`.

Again with the original `ping`:

- `ping -n -c 1 dns.google` queries the DNS server and receives a response before ICMP. This is to translate `dns.google` to `8.8.8.8` or `8.8.4.4`.
- `ping -c 1 dns.google` queries the DNS sever and receives a response before ICMP (to translate to `8.8.8.8` or to `8.8.4.4`) and separately after ICMP (to translate back).

Answer (score 1):

From the man page:

> -n
> Numeric output only. No attempt will be made to lookup symbolic names for host addresses

so the difference is in the output:

```
>ping  whitehouse.gov
PING whitehouse.gov(g2a02-26f0-0082-02b2-0000-0000-0000-2add.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (2a02:26f0:82:2b2::2add)) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from g2a02-26f0-0082-02b2-0000-0000-0000-2add.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (2a02:26f0:82:2b2::2add): icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=7.38 ms
64 bytes from g2a02-26f0-0082-02b2-0000-0000-0000-2add.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (2a02:26f0:82:2b2::2add): icmp_seq=2 ttl=52 time=6.91 ms
64 bytes from g2a02-26f0-0082-02b2-0000-0000-0000-2add.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (2a02:26f0:82:2b2::2add): icmp_seq=3 ttl=52 time=21.6 ms
64 bytes from g2a02-26f0-0082-02b2-0000-0000-0000-2add.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (2a02:26f0:82:2b2::2add): icmp_seq=4 ttl=52 time=7.60 ms
```

```
>ping  -n whitehouse.gov
PING whitehouse.gov(2a02:26f0:82:280::2add) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 2a02:26f0:82:280::2add: icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=10.0 ms
64 bytes from 2a02:26f0:82:280::2add: icmp_seq=2 ttl=52 time=5.63 ms
64 bytes from 2a02:26f0:82:280::2add: icmp_seq=3 ttl=52 time=10.4 ms
64 bytes from 2a02:26f0:82:280::2add: icmp_seq=4 ttl=52 time=12.5 ms
```

Comment: The condition (emphasis mine): "if I ping an *IP address* like `ping 8.8.8.8` …". The questions: "how is there any DNS lookup here?", "does `ping -n 8.8.8.8` do something different?". While everything in your answer is true, the condition is ignored and the questions are not answered.

Comment: I believe the Dell support is confused about the purpose of `-n`. As my example shows, there are reverse DNS calls in addition to the initial call. Historically, you could ping the broadcast address of your LAN, and get answers from several machines.

Comment: @xenoid so you're saying there is no difference when you ping an IP (not a DNS name)?

Comment: I'm saying that `-n` doesn't apply to the name resolution of the `<destination>` parameter of the `ping` command  but only to the name resolution of the address(es) that answer the ping.