# How can I configure the source ip to use for ssh dynamic forwards

Tags: ssh, proxy, socks-proxy

I have a server with multiple ip addresses. On this server a sshd is running and I can connect to it. I can also use this as a socks proxy, using ssh's danymic forwards, which is great. When I use the server as a socks proxy its default outbound ip address is used as source for the ip connections. Is there a way to configure which ip address will be used as source of the socks proxy?

To make an example:
I have a client with the ip address 1.1.1.1 and a server with the ip addresses 2.2.2.2 and 3.3.3.3. 2.2.2.2 is used by default for all outbound ip connections from the server. I want to use ssh's dynamic forward to connect from 1.1.1.1 to 4.4.4.4 with the connection seem to be coming from 3.3.3.3, using the server and ssh as socks proxy.

Is there any way to configure ssh to use 3.3.3.3 as source ip when I make connections using the ssh dynamic forward? A way that avoids to change the general routing on that server, a way that uses maybe netcat and avoids iptables, would be preferred.

Comment: Are `2.2.2.2` and `3.3.3.3` on different interfaces? Related maybe: [How can I open different browsers' windows with different network adapters?](https://superuser.com/q/1515856/432690)

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski unfortunately they are on the same interface.

Comment: This feature doesn't appear implemented in openssh. In connect_next(): https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/V_8_3/channels.c#L4212 there's no bind() between socket() and connect().

Comment: Would a dedicated ssh user on the server be acceptable? Having a far-fetched idea for Linux which requires a dedicated user.

Comment: @A.B thanks or checking in the source code. Yes, a dedicated user would be acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the *openssh* daemon doesn't include this feature currently: the [function `connect_next()`](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/V_8_3/channels.c#L4185) opening connections doesn't use any `bind()` system call, but only `socket()` and `connect()`: there's no provision made for altering the default source address.

---

Here's a route based method using a feature which appeared in Linux 4.10 (thus kernel >= 4.10 is a prerequisite):

- Linux 4.10 added [support for per-UID routing](https://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_4.10#Networking), which avoids having to resort to clumsy *iptables* rules.
- Considering that *sshd* switches to the target ssh user once autheticated, the forwarded connection will be initiated on behalf of that authenticated ssh user on the server rather than *root*.

One can create specific routing rules tied to a specific user: this user (and only this user) will trigger the use of alternate route settings, which will be set the same as the normal routes, *except* for the default source IP address. This requires copying most of the main routing table into the alternate routing table to cover all cases.

So if the Linux system has a dedicated user *from3333* with uid 3333 and this following route as would display `ip route` (inferred from this [comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1585398/how-can-i-configure-the-source-ip-to-use-for-ssh-dynamic-forwards#comment2416075_1585398), please replace 2.2.2.1 with the actual gateway and use the correct interface name), with a secondary address 3.3.3.3 also set on *eth0* but which doesn't appear in the *main* routing table:

```
default via 2.2.2.1 dev eth0
2.2.2.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 2.2.2.2
```

this would require to override the default route, and for dependency reasons (2.2.2.1 must have a route at the time the table 3333 below is looked up, which would happen before the *main* table would have been looked up to provide it) also the LAN route. This gives in the end:

```
# ip route add table 3333 2.2.2.0/24 dev eth0 src 3.3.3.3
# ip route add table 3333 default via 2.2.2.1 dev eth0 src 3.3.3.3
# ip rule add uidrange 3333-3333 lookup 3333
```

Now any packet sent by uid 3333 (aka user *from3333*) will select the routing table 3333 which will select the default source address 3.3.3.3 instead of 2.2.2.2 (unless overridden by the application which won't be the case for *sshd*), but beside this will use the same routes. For example reply packets, which don't have *from3333* as owner, will still select the *main* routing table and this will still work as expected.

This will affect any connection created by user *from3333* on the server, including those initiated through `DynamicForward`/`-D` or `LocalForward`/`-L` on behalf of the ssh running from the *client* system.

If the server has (in order of complexity) additional routes, routing rules or routing tables, this answer has to be adapted on a case-by-case basis, possibly requiring more route duplication work to do.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you very much @A.B