# SOCKS5 proxy using a specific network interface

Tags: networking, proxy, socks-proxy

I want to create a SOCKS5 proxy using a specific network interface. The reason is that I want to use Chrome using a specific network interface, but I can only set up a proxy in Chrome.

I created a SOCKS5 proxy by [goproxy](https://github.com/snail007/goproxy)

```
proxy socks -t tcp -p '127.0.0.1:1080'
```

Although the manual says it can bind to a specific network interface, I was unable to do so.

Any other simple solution is welcome. I just need to create `127.0.0.1:1080` proxy redirecting the traffic from `tun1`.

Comment: "The reason is that I want to use Chrome using a specific network interface" – So the question about SOCKS5 proxy is really an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310), right? What is your OS? Does this answer your question? [*How can I open different browsers' windows with different network adapters?*](https://superuser.com/q/1515856/432690)

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski thanks for the link, which I had already checked. It is not an XY problem. `goproxy` apparently provides a solution by a single command (as opposed to complicated solutions suggested in the link). I mentioned the reason because it is OK for me if someone suggest a solution other than `goproxy`. However, the best solution is to guide me how to bind a network interface in `goproxy`.