# How route software network connection to specified interface (linux)

Tags: linux, networking, routing

```
aprogram -> eth1 -> internet A
bprogram -> eth2 -> internet B
aprogram -> eth2 -> internet B
etc.
```

program (e.g. python script, curl) network communication route to specified interface by custom mechanism.

How can I solve this under linux (debian or ubuntu).

Comment: If the programs are using different target IP addresses, you could easily target per IP address. If they're using the same address, I'm guessing something ugly involving `LD_PRELOAD` or chroot or a VM or something.

Comment: Related: [How can I open different browsers' windows with different network adapters?](https://superuser.com/q/1515856/432690)

Answer (score 0):

You can use policy routing together with `owner` match (iptables) or `skuid`/`skgid` (nftables), and run those programs under different users.

1. Add different nexthops to different tables:

```
ip route add default via 192.0.2.1 table 101
ip route add default via 192.0.2.2 table 102
ip route add default via 192.0.2.3 table 103
```

2. Add rules to use them based on firewall mark:

```
ip rule add fwmark 1 lookup 101
ip rule add fwmark 2 lookup 102
ip rule add fwmark 3 lookup 103
```

3. Add firewall rules to assign those marks to packets based on socket owner:

```
nft add rule filter output meta skuid 1001 mark set 1
nft add rule filter output meta skuid 1002 mark set 2
nft add rule filter output meta skuid 1003 mark set 3
```

or

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner 1001 -j MARK --set-mark 1
iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner 1002 -j MARK --set-mark 2
iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner 1003 -j MARK --set-mark 3
```

Now, programs which are run under UID 1001 will be routed through `192.0.2.1`, and so on.